# directdraw clipper worked incorrectly in Win11

Tags: c++, directdraw

I create a clipper and setHWnd. Code like:

```
m_ddraw->CreateClipper(0, &m_clipper, NULL);
m_clipper->SetHWnd(0, wnd);
m_primarySurface->SetClipper(m_clipper);
```

In windows10, it worked correctly. But in windows11,sometimes it caused
`引发的异常: 0xC0000005: 读取位置 0x0000000000000014 时发生访问冲突。`
When I SetHWnd(0,NULL),it doesn't happen.

Comment: Which line is it actually crashing on? Add error checking to be sure all variables involved are valid and check the return codes from functions that supply them.

Comment: hr = m_primarySurface->Blt(&dstRect, m_offScreenSurface, &srcRect, DDBLT_WAIT, NULL);    The return code is 0x88760037, "DDERR_EXCEPTION", "An exception was encountered while performing the requested operation"

Comment: And the whole program work fine in win10